# iTunes 10.5.1 Missing Multiple Album Art Arrow

Tags: itunes, album-art

So prior to iTunes 10.5.1 the album art viewer in the bottom left of iTunes always displayed arrows on either side of the bar to flip between multiple covers for that particular album. However this appears to have been removed in 10.5.1.

Does anyone know of a way to bring back those arrows? I can still verify that the multiple covers are still there via the Get Info pane but that's a hassle to quickly view multiple covers on lots of songs.

Running OS X Lion 10.7.2 with iTunes 10.5.1.

Also happens with iTunes 10.5.1 in Windows XP SP3